# How can I set a size for html.EditorFor helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the simplest way to set the size of the generated field?

Answer (score 15):

Using CSS:

```
<div class="foo">
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo) %>
</div>
```

and in your CSS file:

```
.foo input {
    width: 200px;
}
```

You could also implement a [custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx) which would allow you to attach any attributes you like to the generated input field such as `class`, `maxlength`, `size`, ...

Comment: brilliant!  And the link to DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider is a big help too.

Answer (score 6):

Another option still: rather than appending the class to the wrapper around your input, you can apply HTML properties to the input itself (doesn't work for "EditorFor" though):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foo, new { @class = "bar" })
```

Further discussion:  http://michaelware.net/post/2010/01/31/Custom-Attributes-When-Using-HtmlTextBoxFor.aspx